# Merging Div-Table-Cells?

Tags: css, html

I have a div-table that is working fine with about 4 columns but now I want to make the items expandable so that another div appears below the entry. The problem is that if I use another div below the table-row its width is getting stucked to the first columns-width.

What I need is a division that ignores the table-layout .. any GOOD solutions for this?

Comment: And why you are using div that looks like a table instead of using real table?

Comment: This looks a lot like tabular data, use a table.

Comment: It's hard to understand why you wouldn't use normal tables for this. (sure looks like tabular data). Then you could use colspan attribute , which has no equivalent in the CSS translation of table layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your final spanning div at the bottom is taking some strange inheritance from your divTable class. In your code, your final div is within the wrapper of divTable. I've amended your code slightly to have the div outside of the divTable div and it spans all columns.

```
<div class="navContent">
<div id="lastRequests" class="divTable">
<div class="divRow bold">
  <div class="divCell c1"> SiteID </div>
  <div class="divCell c2"> Ort </div>
  <div class="divCell c3"> Anfrage </div>
  <div class="divCell c4"> Ergebnis </div>
  <div class="divCell c5"> Datum </div>
</div>
<div class="divRow">
  <div class="divCell c1"> 56831-12481 </div>
  <div class="divCell c2"> gütersloh </div>
  <div class="divCell c3"> 332312, Bielefeld, <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Open.  Web. Business.">Deutscheland</span>, 80.32, 43.23</div>
  <div class="divCell c4"> Proxy </div>
  <div class="divCell c5"> 05.09.2012 20:20:21 </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- move this div here -->
<div style="background-color: #0F9;">
This div should use the whole width
</div>
</div>
```

Edit: While this will work, I agree with everyone else above when they say you should really just use a table for this data instead of trying to replicate table functionality with divs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I do that I have no real table anymore.. I would just like to merge columns by saying that div that it should ignore the parent table.. is that not possible?

Comment: From what I can see, it looks like the div belonging to the `display: table` div automatically assumes that it's a cell of the table. If you want this div to ignore the parent table then as far as I can tell the only way is to remove the div from the containing "table" div. Or just stick to tables :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware CSS doesn't have an option to display a div using a colspan attribute.

I'd recommend either using a real table element if it's to display acrtual tabular data or alternatively simply recreate the layout using divs with the table attributes and your own custom styles.